# How does transport movement work?

Tags: axis-and-allies

Here are a couple of scenarios that my friends and I always fight about when we play Axis and Allies Spring 1942 edition:

- A unit(s) is loaded onto a transport that has not moved yet, then the player moves the transport
- A transport moves one space, then picks up a unit and moves another space.
- A transport "bridges" a unit(s) then moves a space or two.
- A transport moves one space and then bridges a unit(s).
- A transport moves two spaces and then bridges a unit(s).
- A transport moves into a sea space where an enemy has a submerged submarine

If multiple bridges are possible (such as in the bay north of Germany or sea space to the left of said space):

- A transport bridges unit(s), after battle proceeds bridges unit(s) again to a different country (this is complying with the rule that says you can only attack a country once a turn).

One last rule that does not involve transports moving or bridging:

- An airplane (usually a bomber) comes from the land and bombs an unguarded transport and kills it

We have looked at the rulebook countless times and it is pretty vague on some issues. I'm not saying that the rulebook doesn't answer any of our questions, but we certainly can't find any of our answers. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**True, there are so many scenarios that the rulebook doesn't specifically cover**

But most of the points you ask are specified in the rulebook. Taking this [rulebook](http://www.wizards.com/%5CAvalonHill%5Crules%5CAxAl-AnEd_Rules.pdf) (Anniversary: compliance with spring 1942 edition) for instance:

A transport can move between one or two spaces that do not contain an enemy surface ship during combat or non combat phases.  It can load and offload units into free cargo slots before, before or after any of the previous. However load and offload procedures cannot iterate (you can't offload units first and then load). Offloading units ends the transport's actions: If you begin by offloading units of a transport (loaded in previous rounds) then the transport will not move nor load after that.

Other rules apply for a transport engaged in combat.

> A unit(s) is loaded onto a transport that has not moved yet, then the player moves the transport

As long as the transport did not participate in any combat this round, it can be moved, loaded if it has any valid free space and offloaded. It cannot iterate load and offload.

> A transport moves one space, then picks up a unit and moves another
>   space.

It is valid as long as the first move does not put the transport in a seazone containing enemy surface units (thus putting it in combat)

> A transport moves one space and then bridges a unit(s).
>   A transport moves two spaces and then bridges a unit(s).

If bridging means moving land units between adjacent territories in a seazone, it is valid. The transport has: moved (one or two spaces), loaded and offloaded (one or two units).

If between move and load/offload the transport moves to an area with enemy surface units, then the sea combat must be resolved first (amphibious attack).

Remember that no unit can move to any other territory containing enemy troops during non-combat move phase, except for submarines.

> A transport moves into a sea space where an enemy has a submerged
>   submarine

It can be done either in combat move and non-combat move. If done during combat, and you move along a destroyer you CAN choose to engage or not engage the enemy submarines. If you choose to, the transports take part in the combat.

> A transport bridges unit(s), after battle proceeds bridges unit(s)
>   again to a different country (this is complying with the rule that
>   says you can only attack a country once a turn).

No, for two reasons.

Transports that engaged in combat cannot do anything else after (move, load offload).

After offload, the transport actions end.

> An airplane (usually a bomber) comes from the land and bombs an
>   unguarded transport and kills it

If the question is: "Can the transport be destroyed?" the answer is: yes. It is automatically destroyed during combat resolve phase.

I would suggest you install [tripleA](http://triplea.sourceforge.net/mywiki). It is an open source game that can implement A&A ruleset and its different maps; the rules there comply pretty well with the rulebook.

*This were many questions packed in one.. :/ I'll later add the pages references to each sub-answer, or I would welcome anyone editing to add that info.*

Comment: @PaulMarshall in second paragraph: 'Offloading units ends the transport's actions:' .  The bridging question are two scenarios: move 1 space then bridge.  Move 2 spaces then bridge.  It is correct

Comment: Oops, I misread, and now I can't remove my downvote until the answer is edited.

Answer (score 5):

This response is based on the [rules](http://www.axisandallies.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Axis-Allies-Spring-1942-compressed.pdf). I've searched for "transport" and "offload" to find the relevant sections - but there is quite a lot of text. If you want the specific text to each of the rulings below, I can paste it here on your request, but for now you'll get the quick answers:

- A unit(s) is loaded onto a transport that has not moved yet, then the player moves the transport

  - This is ok.
- A transport moves one space, then picks up a unit and moves another space.

  - This is also ok.
- A transport "bridges" a unit(s) then moves a space or two.

  - This is not ok. A transport's move ends where it offloads.
- A transport moves one space and then bridges a unit(s).

  - This is ok. It cannot move any more.
- A transport moves two spaces and then bridges a unit(s).

  - This is ok. It cannot move any more.
- A transport moves into a sea space where an enemy has a submerged submarine.

  - This is ok.
- A transport bridges unit(s), after battle proceeds bridges unit(s) again to a different country (this is complying with the rule that says you can only attack a country once a turn).

  - This is not ok. Generally, transports do stuff either in the combat or noncombat phase.
- An airplane (usually a bomber) comes from the land and bombs an unguarded transport and kills it.

  - This is ok.